# How to achieve fixed position background scroll/reveal effect? jQuery plugin available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, effect

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a jquery plugin, or how to achieve this sort of effect that is visible on the 'collection' section of fashion label [krystalrae.com](http://krystalrae.com/)

[Screen Capture Video](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/396112/Videos/krystal-rae-scroll-effect.mov)

Any tips or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. All you need is some divs that are the same height as the window, with different background images with the property `background-attachment: fixed;`.

```
#one
{
    background: url(http://images.buzzillions.com/images_products/07/02/iron-horse-maverick-elite-mountain-bike-performance-exclusive_13526_100.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

#two
{
    background: url(http://img01.static-nextag.com/image/GMC-Denali-Road-Bike/1/000/006/107/006/610700673.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/mbhLN/

Comment: Well, come back tomorrow :) Thanks!

Comment: I will, quality deserves support :)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for. And even without any javascript, fantastic! A combination of the parallax effect and this is exactly what I am searching for!

Comment: It is worth noting that this will cause problems later with JavaScript. If you build a mobile menu, for example, that pushes the page on expansion, this will not be affected by it like it should.

Answer (score 2):

[**HERE**](http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm) you will find your plugin!

It is Parallax effect.

Comment: @JeroenMoons: It certainly is not.

Comment: Parallax plays with back and foreground to create a sense of depth, the example on the site is just a flat type of effect. NOT parallax :)

Comment: hm, ye, you're right, on that website is not properly Parallax.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to explore these things is to open the page using the [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) plugin in firefox, or the developer console in chrome, and look at the page source.

It also helps, if you try something, and then post what you're having trouble with.

You can also achieve the effect using the jQuery plugins:

1. http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing
2. http://www.smoothdivscroll.com

Comment: Most of the times plugins and scripts are minified and merged, so you can not see everything using FIrefox or Chrome developer console.

Comment: Good point... but at least it's a good place to start digging when you don't know where else to start!

Comment: @AndreaTurri Chrome can _pretty print_ JS back to something readable but I agree that if function and variable names have been obfuscated it still won't be as readable as the original source

Comment: @andyb I use to merge plugins and scripts and will never see what I'm using. And most of the people (good in developing) do that.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I checked with the inspector tools etc and the script is minified, so it was definitely not possible to understand what was going on there.