# Experimenting with bgrnd img scroll, to no avail

Tags: html, css, background-image

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url(SMback.jpg);
color: #ecf2f9;
text-align: center;
-webkit-animation: bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
-ms-animation: bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
-o-animation: bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
}
```

I have no divs set up, just a simple HTML skeleton. The image is appearing without the scroll. What can I be doing better here?

Comment: You can make JSBin. You want to reveal the image on scroll? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260031/how-to-achieve-fixed-position-background-scroll-reveal-effect-jquery-plugin-ava

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to define your keyframes for the bgscroll animation?

```
@keyframes bgscroll
{
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:0 200px;}
}
```

Here's a fiddle to help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/JC9e8/